# Can I use OpenCV on AIX?

Tags: opencv, aix

I developed an image processing library with OpenCV and it works well in Windows, Android(Native) and iOS.

Now I want to build my library to run on AIX server. Unfortunately I couldn't find any guidance for building OpenCV for AIX.

Can you give me any guidance?

Comment: What AIX version are you running? What CPU family? You should be able to compile your code with GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official support for OpenCV on AIX. No community driven project either.

However there is another project maintained by IBM called [IBM AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/).

This project is intended for developers and provides most Linux based, especially GNU based programming languages, tools & libraries to be run on AIX.

You'll have to go through setting up the environment / dependencies, though it must compile just fine. Linux tutorials for [building OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-compile-opencv-sample-code/) using GCC should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might ask the person at [Perzl](http://www.perzl.org/aix/) if he could build it.  He must have a lot of knowledge, tools, and environment already.  I also find it much better than the IBM AIX Toolbox so if you want to try to do it yourself, I would start with his versions instead of IBM's.

Group Bull use to have a similar set of built open source packages but I don't know where they disappeared to.